# select * from table where ticket_id between R1.1.2 And R106.2.3 this is not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying this..

```
select * from table where  between ticket_id R1.1.2 And R106.2.3
```

This will not work.

How to solve this type of problem?

Is there a way for solving the range between varchar datatype(user defined dataType)?

**EDIT**

The R1.1.2 and R106.2.3 above correspond to values of a user defined data type that is represented as a VARCHAR field.  The conceptual ordering of these values needs is based on a hierarchical numbering scheme; e.g.

```
  R1.1.1 < R1.1.2 < R1.2.1 < R2.1.1 < R106.2.3
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and explain what is the error you are getting? And What is `R1.1.2` and `R106.2.3`?

Comment: why you tag this question with java, c#, php without providing code???

Comment: You can't use between in case of varchar data type, which seems to be case with R106.2.3 and R1.1.2

Comment: @ crazy2crack R1.1.2 is ticket_id

Comment: table structure is  id| ticket_id | ticket_name |

Comment: 1| R1.2.2|simple   data stored like this..

Comment: @aadi - how so?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between doesn't mention that restriction (assuming that the OP means `between 'R1.1.2' and 'R106.2.3'`

Comment: @StephenC between ticket_id R1.1.2 and R106.2.3 ..thanx..

Comment: If id field is identity column, then one possible solution for this structure is to get corresponding id for R1.1.1 and R106.2.3, and then use between command with those id.

Comment: @aadi how to use ..thanx...

Comment: Sigh ....  Is `'R2.1.2'` between `'R1.1.2'` and `'R106.2.3'`?

Comment: @aadi select * form table where    between ticket_id R1.1.2 and R106.2.3 find range..

Comment: @StephenC yes  ticket_id contant R1.2.3 ,R2.1.3,R3.1.2,R3.1.3 .......like that..

Comment: Try this one. Select id against given ticket_id, i assume id is int. And then use between command for them.

    select id from table where ticket_id in ( 'R1.106.2', 'R1.1.1')
    select * from table where id between <your lower id value> and <higher id value>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out what you are trying to do now.  For example, you are expecting the query to match `R2.1.2` which lies between `R1.1.2` and `R106.2.3` according to your id scheme.

First of all, your SQL is syntactically invalid.  Assuming that these ids are represented by a `VARCHAR` or similar, you need to use string literals in the SQL; e.g.

```
    select * from table where ticket_id between 'R1.1.2' and 'R106.2.3';
```

But that doesn't solve the problem.  The reason is that the above is equivalent to

```
    select * from table where ticket_id >= 'R1.1.2' 
                        and ticket_id <= 'R106.2.3';
```

where `>=` and `<=` are regular SQL string comparisons.  And that is the problem.  Because according to regular SQL string comparison, `'R2.1.2'` is *larger than* `'R106.2.3'`!!.

In fact, I don't think there is an easy way to express the range check in SQL.  You might be able to do it with a stored procedure that breaks the ticket id string into parts, converts the parts to numbers and compares them.  That is messy and would cause the query optimizer indigestion.  MySQL will end up doing table scans, no matter what indexes you define.

If you want query the ids as number triples / tuples, then you really ought to change the schema, replacing the `VARCHAR` field with three (or more) `INT` fields.

Alternatively, if you know that the fields are in specific ranges, you could represent the id component with leading zeros; e.g.  R0000001.01.02.  However, this breaks if your range assumptions are incorrect; e.g. when you have too many primary ticket numbers.

Comment: thanx... for  suggestion